# Have YouTube send me an email whenever someone replies to my comment

Tags: youtube

YouTube used to email me frequently whenever someone would reply to my comment. I loved this feature and would never miss a reply and always replied back. Now when I go under *Settings* → *Email* there is no option to get an email for each reply.

These are the options I get:

```
Send me emails when:

[x] Someone subscribes to my channel
[x] Someone leaves a comment on my channel
[x] Someone leaves a comment or response on my video
[x] I receive a private message or a shared video
[x] YouTube Live Event Notifications
[ ] Do not send me any emails
```

They are all checked.

Is there any way I could receive an email when someone replies to my comment?

Comment: Have you checked your spam folder? Perhaps the messages are being mis-tagged as spam.

Comment: wow. you are right it is in the spam folder. Its strange since i didnt mark it as spam. I just assumed because there is no option to send an email after any reply it was youtube's fault. Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user Al Everett states, you should ensure that the message is not being sent to the spam folder. If you do find the messages there, I suggest selecting the message, and choosing the option to `create filter`.

Choose the option `Never send to spam` to avoid this happening again.